# An msvsmon.exe that supports SQL attach wasn't found

Tags: remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When I setup a remote debug env to attach the process to my application exe, I
always get the following error message "An msvsmon.exe that supports
SQL attach wasn't found on "RemoteServerName". SQL attach aborted."
How could I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Tried Using both the versions for Debugging-No Luck

Tried attaching without Authentication--No Luck

[Info]
Trying to attach from Win764 to Win32Xp Machine using x86 Debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things that worked for me:

- Try Closing VStudio and relaunching.
- If not, reboot helps[I that not reliable one,but something worth trying].